# SAX plot and plot.ts on same graph

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I could plot the SAX representation of time series using

```
SAX.plot( x, w=10, alpha=3)
```

[image: Figure 1]

**How to plot both the SAX representation and time series in same graph?(as shown in figure below)**

[image: Figure 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the time series to the same plot using `par(new=TRUE)`. This will overlay the second plot on the first plot.

1. `plot(x, type="l", main="SAX Plot")`
2. `par(new=TRUE)`
3. `SAX.plot( x, w=10,alpha=3)`